# Eclipse error occured during running Main class [main method]

Tags: java, eclipse

I have eclipe (version 2019-03) [ide] installed in my pc. Also i have windows 10. And i use java 11. So, i have this code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.aegean.ccsl;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


/**
 * @author steve
 *
 */
public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    //Lists and parameters declaration
    private static List<IotDevice> iot_list = new ArrayList<IotDevice>();
    private static List<Cluster> cluster_list = new ArrayList<Cluster>();
    private static List<Double> rate_list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    private static int M, Bt, P, No, cell, fc, min_d, f, F;
    private static double B, h;
    private static int h_mobile, h_base;

    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");

    /**
     * Main method.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
```

When i right click on Main class and run as Java Application then eclipse throws a window: [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R88kl.png . Any possible reasons to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes my friend. But none of these solutions can fix this..

Comment: Where's this Main class? In a Java Project created by that wizard? In a Source folder in such a project?

Comment: In a Maven Project by wizard. Under package com.aegean.ccsl.

Comment: Hard to say so far what Eclipse regarded as `selection`. Look at Run configurations, there should be a launch shortcut with more info.